# Plot 3D density plot from many 2D arrays

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a 3D density plot from many 2D numpy arrays of the same shape. Each [x,y] coordinate returns an intensity (how dense it is at that point).

I cannot figure out how to plot this using matplotlib

I'm able to successfully get a contour plot by just plotting one 2D array, or using imshow to get a nice slice of my density at a certain 'z' cut, but just plotting that 2D array.

I have an object: `data`, which when I apply the method `slice()` and pass in an integer from 0 to 480, I get a 2D array of that 'z' cross section:

```
plt.imshow(data.slice(200))
```

[image]

I want to  be able to plot a density map by iterating over `data.slice(n)` for n-> 0 to  480 and plot that on a single image.

I'm not sure how to do such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of slices that you want to view as a density map from one side, you can average over all the cells along a given axis and them view that as an image.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

def plot_projections(d):
    # project onto the appropriate plane by averaging
    d_mean_0 = d.mean(axis=0)
    d_mean_1 = d.mean(axis=1)
    d_mean_2 = d.mean(axis=2)

    plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
    plt.imshow(d.mean(axis=0), cmap='rainbow')
    plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
    plt.imshow(d.mean(axis=1), cmap='rainbow')
    plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)
    plt.imshow(d.mean(axis=2), cmap='rainbow')
    plt.show()


# random seeded 10x10x10 array 
d = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(10,10,10))

plot_projections(d)
```

[image]

```
# pack matrix with 10s along one plane
for i in range(len(d)):
    d[2][i] = np.array([10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10])

plot_projections(d)
```

[image]